# Laravel: Set custom Authentication user as the logged in user

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a custom authentication class which get's called from middleware, this will forward the user to AWS Cognito Hosted UI, the user will login then get returned to the application with a authorization code. This code is then exchanged for the `access_token`, `id_token` and `refresh_token`.

Once the `access_token` and `id_token` has been validated using the **jwks** keys I can extract the users email address and then return this within the `User` model which extends `Authenticatable`. Then i'd like to use `$user` within my Twig templates the same way i can with the default login system for Laravel.

Below is my code:

```php
// config/auth.php

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'cognito',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User\User::class,
        ],
```

```php
// app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php

public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();
    
    Auth::extend('cognito', static function ($app, $name, array $config) {
        return new CognitoUserProvider(new User());
    });
}
```

```php
// app/Auth/CognitoUserProvider.php

<?php

namespace App\Auth;

use App\Models\User;
use Firebase\JWT\JWT;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use CoderCat\JWKToPEM\JWKConverter;

class CognitoUserProvider
{
    private $user;
    private $clientId;
    private $clientSecret;
    private $poolId;
    private $region;
    private $domain;
    private $guzzle;
    
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->clientSecret = config('app.aws_cognito_client_secret');
        $this->poolId = config('app.aws_cognito_pool_id');
        $this->clientId = config('app.aws_cognito_client_id');
        $this->region = config('app.aws_region');
        $this->domain = implode('.', [
            config('app.aws_cognito_domain'),
            'auth',
            config('app.aws_region'),
            'amazoncognito.com'
        ]);
        $this->guzzle = new Client();
        $this->user = $user;
    }
    
    /**
     * @return User|bool|void
     */
    public function authenticate()
    {    
        if (request()->input('code')) {
            $tokens = $this->exchangeTokens();
        
            $accessToken = $this->validateToken($tokens['access_token']);
            $userToken = $this->validateToken($tokens['id_token']);
        
            if (!$accessToken || !$userToken) {
                dd('JsonException Exception Occurred.');
            }
        
            request()->session()->put('access_token', $accessToken);
            request()->session()->put('id_token', $userToken);
            request()->session()->put('refresh_token', $tokens['refresh_token']);
        
            $this->user->setAttribute('email', $userToken->email);
            $this->user->setAttribute('first_name', 'Martyn');
            $this->user->setAttribute('last_name', 'Ball');
            $this->user->setAttribute('id', 5);
        
            return $this->user;
        }
        
        if (request()->session()->has('refresh_token')) {
            return $this->refreshToken();
        }
    
        $this->sendToLoginPage();
    }
    
    /**
     * @param $token
     *
     * @return false|object
     */
    private function validateToken($token)
    {
        $domain = implode('.', [ 'cognito-idp', $this->region, 'amazonaws.com' ]);
        $jwks = file_get_contents("https://$domain/{$this->poolId}/.well-known/jwks.json");

        try {
            $jwks = collect(json_decode($jwks, true, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR)['keys']);
    
            $jwks = $jwks->keyBy('kid')->map(static function ($current) {
                return (new JWKConverter())->toPEM($current);
            })->toArray();
    
            $jwt = new JWT();
            $jwt::$leeway = config('app.jwt_leeway');
    
            return $jwt::decode($token, $jwks, ['RS256']);
        } catch (\JsonException $e) {
            return false;
        }
        
    }
    
    /**
     * @return false|mixed
     */
    private function exchangeTokens()
    {
        $params = [
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
            'client_id' => $this->clientId,
            'code' => request()->input('code'),
            'redirect_uri' => 'https://localhost/',
        ];
        $result = $this->guzzle->post("https://{$this->domain}/oauth2/token?".http_build_query($params), [
            'headers' => [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Authorization' => 'Basic '.base64_encode("{$this->clientId}:{$this->clientSecret}")
            ]
        ]);
        if ($result->getStatusCode() === 200) {
            try {
                return json_decode($result->getBody()->getContents(), true, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);
            } catch (\JsonException $e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        
        return false;
    }
    
    /**
     * @return void
     */
    private function sendToLoginPage(): void
    {
        $query = http_build_query([
            'client_id' => $this->clientId,
            'response_type' => 'code',
            'redirect_uri' => 'https://localhost/'
        ]);
        header("Location: https://{$this->domain}/login?$query&scope=email+openid");
        exit;
    }
    
    /**
     * @return void
     */
    public function logout(): void
    {
        dd(debug_backtrace());
    }
}
```

Comment: you should log them in via the authentication system then (the regular `web` guard) ... are you really going to be authenticating with this 3rd party every single request the user makes? as that is what the custom guard would be doing, which you don't need ... authenticate with the 3rd party to get what you want, then just log them in to the normal `web` guard

Comment: @lagbox I need to refresh the token each time to ensure the token is still valid, as the user can sign out of other places as this is SSO.